# Need Help for interpretation of Error Handling Scenario for Mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

My Mulesoft POC contains globalErrorHandler as well as localErrorHandler having OnErrorContinue scope, I noticed yet it throws a MULE:EXPRESSION error ,Can anyone let me know the reason for it . The code is below enclosed with the pic of the flow .

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="f8f3f4bb-341a-43ec-acf8-9ed33419f5ef" basePath="/error" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8082" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <configuration doc:name="Configuration" doc:id="689a9085-287e-43e4-8e3d-5eeac857dc64" defaultErrorHandler-ref="globalError_Handler"/>
    <flow name="example-errorFlow" doc:id="c37abd41-2143-4da1-848a-a8c240853b60" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="9cda3f2d-a48d-40bd-96a4-54d856d0438e" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/"/>
        <set-payload value='"MAIN"' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="a1b3890f-6157-4716-84d3-8f6ccd6e9af5" />
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="9fc2571b-7038-4359-82db-be624d48b343" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
["RESPONSE"] ++ payload ]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <error-handler >
            <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue" type= "HTTP:NOT_FOUND" doc:id="e6f2b028-e3ca-4eff-b878-0f41dd53d693" >
                <set-payload value='"HTTP:NOT_FOUND"' doc:name='"HTTP:NOT_FOUND"' doc:id="c465edf3-bbac-4fca-bfb1-f2a6678e1173" />
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>
    </flow>
    <error-handler name="globalError_Handler" doc:id="05e153b7-d663-4aa1-85c0-8fefbf76c39b" >
        <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue" doc:id="c0e80820-db0f-4b3f-b0e2-c74c47e3a5e7" >
            <set-payload value="global Error Handler" doc:name="global Error Handler" doc:id="0055b184-4dd6-4d20-8284-27534570f723" />
        </on-error-continue>
    </error-handler>
</mule>
```

**FlowImage**
[image]

Comment: You need to add the complete error message so we can understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from your Transform component but you are handling only HTTP:NOT FOUND error.

Handle all exceptions as described here

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/OnErrorContinue.html

In particular - simple remove error type and you will see actual message and can fix it.
Post it here and we can help.

Comment: Yes agreed , but I am looking to understand is there any hierarchy of errors as the MULE:EXPRESSION will not be caught and it would only look for HTTP:NOT FOUND error ?

Answer (score 0):

In the transform you're trying to use ++ function with an Array and String which is incorrect (in your case its `["RESPONSE"] ++ payload` where `payload = "MAIN"`), coming to flow error handling you're handling a specific error from `HTTP` namespace, whereas the error you get is from `MULE` namespace of type `EXPRESSION`, so thats the reason the local error handler is unable to handle that error.

To handle this either use `MULE:EXPRESSION` or `MULE:ANY` which can serve as a parent error type for `MULE:EXPRSSION` and `HTTP:NOT_FOUND` errors

The `MULE` namespace is an implicit namespace you can also call it as a parent namespace which can handle any runtime based error.

To better understand errors, their hierarchy and global error handler consider visiting the resource mentioned below.

https://youtu.be/9WcG9teCrvo